# Proof that the left ideal I of prime norm in maximal order can be written as I = ON + Oα

Tags: ideals, quaternion-algebras

It seems there is a well-known fact that if $O$ is a maximal order in quaternion algebra $B$ and $I$ is a left $O-$ideal such that $nrd(I) = N$ is
prime, then $I = ON + Oα$ with $gcd(N^2, nrd(α)) = N$.

I would like to at least intuitively understand why it is so. The proof [here](https://ntnuopen.ntnu.no/ntnu-xmlui/bitstream/handle/11250/2778397/no.ntnu%3Ainspera%3A77742017%3A21554595.pdf?sequence=1) (Proposition 4.12) looks at it locally and first shows that $I_{(p)} = O_{(p)}$ for $p \neq N$. Because $I$ is locally principal we have $I_{(N)} = O_{(N)} \alpha$ for some $\alpha \in B$. It then proceeds to say
$$I_{(p)} = O_{(p)} = (ON + O\alpha)_{(p)}.$$

I don't see why the second equality ($O_{(p)} = (ON + O\alpha)_{(p)}$) holds?